# RecyclerView not displaying data from firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebase-security

Hi so I'm trying to retrieve data from my firestore and display it to a recyclerview, but I only get the listview without the actual data. Someone pleasee tell me what's wrong. Here's my adapter "AmenityAdapter" code

```
package eu.tutorials.newuserdemo

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class AmenityAdapter(private val amenityList:ArrayList<AmenityData>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AmenityAdapter.AmenityViewHolder>() {

    inner class AmenityViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val amenName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amenityName)
        val amenQuantity: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amenityQuantity)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AmenityViewHolder {

        val itemView=
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return AmenityViewHolder(itemView)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AmenityViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.amenName.text = amenityList[position].amenityName
        holder.amenQuantity.text = amenityList[position].amenityQuantity

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return amenityList.size
    }


}
```

And here's my view amenities activity

```
package eu.tutorials.newuserdemo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class ViewAmenities : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var amenityList: ArrayList<AmenityData>

    private  var db = Firebase.firestore

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_amenities)

        supportActionBar?.hide()

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        amenityList = arrayListOf()



        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("amenity").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                if(!it.isEmpty){
                    for (data in it.documents){
                        val amenity: AmenityData? = data.toObject(AmenityData::class.java)
                        if (amenity != null) {
                            amenityList.add(amenity)
                        }

                        }
                    recyclerView.adapter = AmenityAdapter(amenityList)
                    }

                }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

    }
 }
```

And here's the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_nude"
    tools:context=".ViewAmenities">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried almost every solution suggested out there but I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Is any of the listeners triggered?

Comment: i had tweaked the firestore rules and the failure listener worked, so the failure listener does get triggered

Comment: So you say that when you have the correct rules onSuccess is triggered but you get an empty list, right? Please also your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.